# PHP json_encode and XSS

Tags: php, javascript, xss, json

This question has been asked many times. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062146/is-json-encode-sufficient-xss-protection), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816787/json-php-to-javascript-safe-or-not/6817147#6817147) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913503/xss-creating-a-javascript-object-using-phps-json-encode?rq=1)

Based on the answers in those questions I did some tests and I'm forced to ask the same question again as none of the answers appear to be correct (at-least to me). Please correct me if my understanding of subject is bad.

I'm working on an API for a web app that outputs JSON response. The server side response is handled by `json_encode` in PHP. Since, this would be a public API I would want to prevent any XSS due to incorrect client side implementations by a deveopler consuming the API.

For my test I did the following on server side:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
$bad = array('bad_key' => 'alert("hi");');
echo json_encode($bad);
```

On client side I'm using jQuery AJAX that automatically parses the JSON recieved. Initially this did not appear to show any XSS issue. Then I passed `response.bad_key` to `eval()`.

```
eval(response.bad_key);
```

This immediately resulted in execution of string in `bad_key`. I'm aware that use of `eval` is bad and should be avoided. However, that's something that I know and cannot ensure the other developer follows the same practice. To avoid such scenarios a solution would be to perform server side encoding. For this let's say I use `htmlspecialchars`.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
$bad = array('bad_key' => htmlspecialchars('alert("hi");'));
echo json_encode($bad);
```

This, though it does not execute `alert("hi");` client-side but breaks the JS code due to presence of `&`. `json_encode` with the option `JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6817147/1213627) does not help either.

So how do I prevent XSS in such a scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not need to prevent "XSS" in this scenario. If someone is stupid enough to execute some random data you send him as JavaScript there is nothing you can do against it. Actually, if you did escape something to prevent it he would probably unescape it to make it work again.

Note that using `eval` to *parse* the JSON string is somewhat safe (assuming you send valid JSON) - even though it's discouraged in any modern browser that has a native `JSON.parse()`.
But in your example you do not use it to parse JSON but to execute some random string of data! When anyone does that it means that he WANTS it to be executed as code - so it's not XSS but "working as intended"!

Comment: +1 You cannot protect people from their own stupidity. Sanitizing any and all *potentially* "dangerous" strings out leaves you with basically no content at all.

Comment: @thiefmaster Yeah, this is a gray area where I really cannot do something to prevent things from going wrong due to bad implementation by others. I thought may be I was missing something. Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: It would not even be "bad implementation" - it would require the other user to actively execute some of the data as JavaScript code.